# How to replace Android image drawable (glide) with a Lottie animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-glide, lottie

I wanted to replace these three states WiFi images sequence (connect, connecting, connected) with one Lottie animation containing the 3 states:

1. When it's **idle**, it should display a still frame from the WiFi Lottie animation.
2. When a button is **pressed**: it plays the WiFi Lottie animation from frame x to frame y.
3. When it **connects**: it displays a still frame from the WiFi Lottie animation.

This is the Java code I need to modify:

```
protected void loadIcon() {
    if (state == WifiState.IDLE) {
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.ic_connect).into(connectButtonTextView);
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.ic_connect).into(connectButtonTextView);

    } else if (state == WifiState.CONNECTING_WIFI || state == WifiState.CONNECTING_CREDENTIALS) {
        connectButtonTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.is_connecting).into(connectButtonTextView);
        
    } else if (state == WifiState.CONNECTED) {
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.ic_connected).into(connectButtonTextView);
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.ic_connected).into(connectButtonTextView);
        connectButtonTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

Comment: you cant add lottie file file to normal imageview using glide.Please follow https://lottiefiles.com/blog/working-with-lottie/getting-started-with-lottie-animations-in-android-app  foe more details.

Comment: Yes i know, but since i have almost 0 java knowledge and I've just started learning it, would you please help me replace the glide with lottie anims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace you `ImageView` with this

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
     android:id="@+id/animationView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:lottie_url="REPLACE_JSON_URL"
     app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
     app:lottie_loop="true"/>
```

in xml file.
Replace your activity glide code with the below code and give your json file according to your if condition.

```
animationView.setAnimation("abc.json")
animationView.playAnimation()
animationView.loop(true)
```